# Select a column value with at least two records with a condition (PYSPARK)

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I started from a csv file, converted to the dataframe below:

[image]

Continuing to work on dataframe and using PYSPARK, I need to find values in the `sensorID` column that have at least two records that satisfy the condition (`PM10 > 50`).

Then, I need to have an output with the value of `sensorID` and a `count` of how many times the condition is met.

The output should be: **sensorID: s1; 2** (count of PM10>50)

I tried:

```
rdd.select("sensorID").where(col("PM10") > 50).count().show()
```

that gives me an error.
I tried without `.show()`, but I can't select only the value with at least two records (I tried `groupBy` and `orderBy`, but it's always wrong).

I'm having a problem putting them together properly.
I hope you can explain to me where I am going wrong, thanks.

Comment: Can you share the proper code being used and the expected output?

Comment: [Please avoid uploading images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Use text formatting instead.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry, I'm new here on Stack and I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional sum aggregation:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("s1", "2016-01-01", 20.5), ("s2", "2016-01-01", 30.1), ("s1", "2016-01-02", 60.2),
    ("s2", "2016-01-02", 20.4), ("s1", "2016-01-03", 55.5), ("s2", "2016-01-03", 52.5)
], ["sensorId", "date", "PM10"])

df1 = df.groupBy("sensorId").agg(
    F.sum(F.when(F.col("PM10") > 50., 1)).alias("count")
).filter("count > 1")

df1.show()
#+--------+-----+
#|sensorId|count|
#+--------+-----+
#|      s1|    2|
#+--------+-----+
```